# How to analyze the time complexity and space complexity of the edit distance using the Depth First Search (DFS) +memo approach?

Tags: time-complexity, depth-first-search, space-complexity, edit-distance

it is well known that the edit-distance problem could be solved using the iterative DP approach. However, if we solve the problem using the recursive Depth First Search (DFS) + memo approach, how to calculate the time complexity? Why?

The codes are provided as below

```
class Solution:
    def minDistance(self, word1, word2):
        return self.dfs(word1, 0, word2, 0, {})

    def dfs(self, word1, p1, word2, p2, memo): ### p1, p2 refer to the current position in word1, word2 respectively
        if p1 == len(word1):
            return len(word2[p2:]) ### termination of the recursion
        if p2 == len(word2):
            return len(word1[p1:]) ### termination of the recursion
        if (p1, p2) in memo:    ### the key of the memo is the two positions, value is the mini edit distance for word1[p1:] and word2[p2:]
            return memo[(p1, p2)]
        if word1[p1] == word2[p2]:  ### Case1: word1[p1] equals to word2[p2]
            temp = self.dfs(word1, p1+1, word2, p2+1, memo)
        else:  ### Case2: word1[p1] not equals to word2[p2].  
            temp = min(self.dfs(word1, p1, word2, p2+1, memo), self.dfs(word1, p1+1, word2, p2, memo), self.dfs(word1, p1+1, word2, p2+1, memo)) + 1
        memo[(p1, p2)] = temp
        return temp
```

Comment: Is the question is about Depth First Search ? If so edit the tags: "DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]"

Comment: Thanks, c0der! I will revise it accordingly